# Calling javascript functions from view in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I have a pretty simple problem with calling javascript functions from within a view. In Rails 2 I would do...

```
= javascript_tag "name(arguments)"
```

where the javascript function "name" was located in my application.js file. However, this does not appear to work in Rails 3? Or am I missing something? I have been searching Google for some time without finding an answer.

**UPDATE:**

OK, so I looked at the source of the two different ways (using the javascript_tag and the haml javascript filter) as suggested. And this is very strange because the html source appears to be identical? Apart from a difference in double and single quotes in declaring the script type.

**FIRST:** using the javascript_tag which ***does not work***

```
= javascript_tag "number_interval(#{fact.current_value}, #{fact.growth_per_second}, #{fact.decimal_number}, '#{dom_id(fact, "number")}'"
```

Source...

```
<div id='number_number_interval_727'>loading</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
number_interval(6952596670.36814, 2.33002440293917, 0, 'number_number_interval_727'
//]]>
</script>
```

**SECOND:** using the haml javascript filter ***and it works***

```
:javascript
  number_interval(#{fact.current_value}, #{fact.growth_per_second}, #{fact.decimal_number}, '#{dom_id(fact, "number")}')
```

Source...

```
<div id='number_number_interval_727'>loading</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
number_interval(6952596917.02179, 2.33002440293917, 0, 'number_number_interval_727')
//]]>
</script>
```

Well, I guess I'll just stick with the haml filter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
= javascript_tag "number_interval(#{fact.current_value}, #{fact.growth_per_second}, #{fact.decimal_number}, '#{dom_id(fact, "number")}'"
```

is missing the closing parenthesis for the `number_interval` function.  I think that it should be:

```
= javascript_tag "number_interval(#{fact.current_value}, #{fact.growth_per_second}, #{fact.decimal_number}, '#{dom_id(fact, "number")}')"
```

Comment: Wow... can't believe I missed that one :)

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine pointed me to the fact that there is a javascript helper in haml. Apparently, I can call javascript functions by using...

```
:javascript
  name_of_function(arguments)
```

This works, but of course only with haml.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the right syntax on [link text](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0.beta3/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag)

and Check if you have included the javascript defaults in your file.As this working for me in RAILS 3 also

Comment: The syntax is correct and javascript defaults are included. The javascript_tag "alert('All is good')" also works, but if I for example put "alert('all is good')" into a function of its own, place it in application.js, and then try to call it with javascript_tag it does not. But maybe this is not the way to do it.

Comment: Well then you have an error in your function or syntax.  Post your function code, exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but... is application.js included in your layout?

One option to try is to hand-code the js function-call into your view in "real" javascript - just to see if it works. eg

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  name(arguments)
</script>
```

Then you can be sure it's not the js itself (or lack thereof) at fault.

Comment: Yes, the application.js is included. I guess the :javascript filter in haml does what you suggest,...and it works.

Comment: Ok... so the next option is to view-source on what is put into the html when you do the one that's breaking... and compare that to what's int he source when you use the haml-version.
if you can copy the relevant source-code into your question (above) we can disect it and see what's going on.